# Change VUE component inside module before loading

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have component like:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <some-module />
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import SomeModule from '../../node_modules/somemodule/SomeModule.vue'
  import MyComponent from 'MyComponent.vue'

  @Component({
    components: {
        SomeModule
     }
  })
  export default class AppMyRootComponent extends Vue {
  }
</script>
```

And I know that this module have subcomponent, so this module could be like:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <module-component />
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import ModuleComponent from 'ModuleComponent'

  @Component({
    components: {
        ModuleComponent
     }
  })
  export default class SomeModule extends Vue {
  }
</script>
```

I need to use `SomeModule` with source code unchanged, but I need to change `ModuleComponent` to `MyComponent` when I use it.

Comment: [Dynamic & Async Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

Comment: @EVILD How this should help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to write own class extends this one from module, and use own class in project. I can provide own internal component that change original one.